# Amazon AWS communication of instances in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

Im in the middle of deploying a server on Amazon for my application. Therefore I decided to use EC2 **ubunutu 14.04 64-bit t2.micro instances** (free). I want to scale up the hardware later after testing my application. My goal is to build up a server system that is prepared to scale up when i want to. So the system design looks like the following:

```
                              VPC (default)
           ___________________________________________
          |                                           |      
WWW <-----|----> NGINX <----> EXPRESS <------> NEO4J  |
          |___________________________________________|
```

And later I want to be able to scale it up to sth like this:

```
                              VPC (default)
           _________________________________________________
          |                                                 |
          |               –– EXPRESS --           -- NEO4J  |
          |              |             |         |          |   
WWW <-----|----> NGINX -- -- EXPRESS -- -- ELB -- -- NEO4J  |
          |              |             |                    |
          |               -- EXPRESS --                     |
          |_________________________________________________|
```

But for now, i have the first System design setup. I created 3 Ubuntu instances. The first one is setup with **nginx** for the purpose of reverse proxy, gzip compression and load balancing. The nginx instance can be reached via **http on Port 80**. The **express** instance contains my **node/javascript** code where the server is running on **Port 3000**. the last instance is running with **NEO4J** as my NOSQL DB. The Problem now is, that i can't let the instances communicate with each other in my default VPC. Or to be more precise, I first want the nginx server (Port 80) to communicate with my express server (Port 3000) which are on different t2.micro instances Like the First design I showed above.

I created a nginx config file called "express" in the sites-available directory and created a symbolic link in the sites-enabled directory refercing the "express" config file.

the **nginx express config** file looks like the following:

```
upstream nodes{
        server PRIVATE_IP:3000;
        keepalive 8;
}

server{
        listen *:80;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://nodes;

                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;

        }
}
```

I'm trying to communicate with my express instance with the PRIVATE_IP.

security group of my **nginx** instance:
[image]

security group of my **express** instance:
[image]

security group of my **neo4j** instance:
[image]

I can request the default html of nginx (Welcome to Nginx ...) via 
`http://PUBLIC_DNS_OF_NGINX`.
But when I'm requesting sth reversed proxied to express `http://PUBLIC_DNS_OF_NGINX/test` 
my express server does not give back a response (not reached by nginx).

But i can reach the express instance directly and getting back a response via 
http://PUBLIC_DNS_OF_EXPRESS:3000/test.

EDIT: I did ssh into nginx server and curl http://PRIVATE_DNS_OF_EXPRESS:3000/test and http://PRIVATE_IP_OF_EXPRESS:3000/test and both worked. So I gues there is a mistake on the side of the nginx server. It's maybe the config I guess, but still need your help ...

Comment: If your server is running on port 3000, you need to open that port in security group attached to your server instance

Comment: @DusanBajic is right, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: sry, did a mistake. I'm already allowing port 3000 Inbound in express security group. I'm editing the question

Comment: `netstat -a -n | grep 3000`.  My guess is that you have express listening on/bound to the loopback adapter, 127.0.0.1, which, of course, would not be accessible from anywhere.

Comment: I can reach the express server/instance from outside, just my nginx server can't reach the express server. On my nginx server I can also curl sth from the express server, so I gues there is sth wrong with my nginx settings

Comment: Check nginx error logs - any messages there about your request?

Comment: no error logs  in /var/log/nginx/error.log (got the error.log location from nginx.conf)

Comment: Do check the solution that i have mentioned below, this should solve out the issue with nginx not able to connect to express.

Comment: sry, your solution is actually wrong ... It also works without the appending "/" int he config. Maybe this functionallity depends on the version of nginx ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually is working now, the configs were right all the time and I did not need a "appending a /". I just created a new Instance and copied all of the configurations into that new instance, but now everything seems to work fine. There were some setting problems since the beginning ....

Answer (score 0):

Your setup should be in following way

1) Open 80 or 443 port on security group which is assigned to Nginx server.
2) open custom TCP port 3000 on security group assigned to javascript server(Express). Allow your traffic on port 3000 either from nginx machines private ip or for Security group assigned to nginx machine (AWS console allows this)
3)Finally again open port of nosql DB on security group assigned to DB server and allow traffic from java script (Express) servers IP or java script servers security group.

Note: Please avoid allowing all traffic on 22 port in security group just for security reasons

Comment: But I'm allowing communication from everywhere, should'nt this work then ? Of course, i will change the settings for port 22, thx for your concern.

Comment: OS IPtables can be one of the reason then. Try to flush or stop iptables and check once for connectivity

Comment: Could the Iptables really be the problem on an Amazon Ubuntu AMI ? I did not change anything on the default settings, so i would be the first of thousands with that problem ...

Comment: ssh into nginx instance and test with `curl -v http://EXPRESS_PRIVATE_IP:3000`, see if you can connect

Comment: `curl -v http://EXPRESS_PRIVATE_IP:3000` and `curl -v http://EXPRESS_PRIVATE_DNS_NAME:3000` seems to work. so the problem lies in the nginx config I gues.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me like a simple issue, wherein your nginx config for routing to express is wrongly configured. You have missed out appending a `/` at the end of `proxy_pass` directive because of which `nginx` will reroute to `http://nodestest`. Rewrite your nginx config to this

```
upstream nodes{
    server PRIVATE_IP:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}

server{
    listen *:80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nodes/; //appended forward slash

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

Once the config change has been made reload `nginx` using the command `sudo service nginx reload`

Comment: `proxy_pass http://nodes` and `proxy_pass http://nodes/` do same inside `location /`. Please, read http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass